# Programmatically zip files from SharePoint document library (no 3rd party tools)

Tags: c#, sharepoint, zip

what I'm trying to achieve, is to have an InfoPath form (.Net 4.5 c# code) in a SharePoint form library and on button press certain files from a document library are getting wrapped up into a zip file.
The difficulty is, that I can't use 3rd party tools.

My approach looks at the moment like this:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
           {
               using (SPSite siteCollection = new SPSite(site))
               {
                   using (SPWeb oWeb = siteCollection.OpenWeb())
                   {
                       //Identifies the mode we will be using - the default is Create
                       ZipArchiveMode mode = ZipArchiveMode.Create;
                        using (ZipArchive zipFile = ZipFile.Open(archiveFullName, mode))
                        {
                            foreach (string file in files)
                            {
                                //Adds the file to the archive
                                zipFile.CreateEntryFromFile(file, Path.GetFileName(file), compression);
                            }
}
}
}
});
```

The Problem in this is, that the ZipFile Open()-Method (and maybe the 'CreateEntryFromFile'-Method as well) doesn't take URL's as an argument and throws a NotSupportedException.
Has anyone an idea on how to fix this problem?

Thank you in advance.
Best regards
greven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're creating a brand new zip file instead of updating an existing one (let me know if my assumption is wrong). If you want to create a zip archive in memory instead of creating the zip file on disk then you can use the [ZipArchive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.compression.ziparchive.aspx) class.

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create))
    {
        archive.CreateEntryFromFile(fileToPutInZip, fileNameInZip);
    }

    // To get the zip bytes (i.e. to return in HTTP response maybe):
    byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();

    // TODO: Do something with zip bytes
}
```